# How to make ClickPad double-tap more reliable

Tags: touchpad

Double-tapping on text so it gets highlighted is very unreliable, and seems to work at random. Single tapping is never a problem though (I set **taps** to mean **clicks** with `synclient TapButton1=1`).

Here's what my configuration looks like:

```
$ synclient
Parameter settings:
    LeftEdge                = 1765
    RightEdge               = 5371
    TopEdge                 = 1638
    BottomEdge              = 4470
    FingerLow               = 25
    FingerHigh              = 30
    MaxTapTime              = 180
    MaxTapMove              = 234
    MaxDoubleTapTime        = 180
    SingleTapTimeout        = 180
    ClickTime               = 100
    EmulateMidButtonTime    = 0
    EmulateTwoFingerMinZ    = 282
    EmulateTwoFingerMinW    = 7
    VertScrollDelta         = 106
    HorizScrollDelta        = 106
    VertEdgeScroll          = 0
    HorizEdgeScroll         = 0
    CornerCoasting          = 0
    VertTwoFingerScroll     = 1
    HorizTwoFingerScroll    = 0
    MinSpeed                = 1
    MaxSpeed                = 1.75
    AccelFactor             = 0.0375235
    TouchpadOff             = 2
    LockedDrags             = 0
    LockedDragTimeout       = 5000
    RTCornerButton          = 0
    RBCornerButton          = 0
    LTCornerButton          = 0
    LBCornerButton          = 0
    TapButton1              = 1
    TapButton2              = 2
    TapButton3              = 3
    ClickFinger1            = 1
    ClickFinger2            = 3
    ClickFinger3            = 2
    CircularScrolling       = 0
    CircScrollDelta         = 0.1
    CircScrollTrigger       = 0
    PalmDetect              = 0
    PalmMinWidth            = 10
    PalmMinZ                = 200
    CoastingSpeed           = 20
    CoastingFriction        = 50
    PressureMotionMinZ      = 30
    PressureMotionMaxZ      = 160
    PressureMotionMinFactor = 1
    PressureMotionMaxFactor = 1
    GrabEventDevice         = 1
    TapAndDragGesture       = 1
    AreaLeftEdge            = 0
    AreaRightEdge           = 0
    AreaTopEdge             = 0
    AreaBottomEdge          = 0
    HorizHysteresis         = 26
    VertHysteresis          = 26
    ClickPad                = 1
    RightButtonAreaLeft     = 3568
    RightButtonAreaRight    = 0
    RightButtonAreaTop      = 4107
    RightButtonAreaBottom   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaLeft    = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaRight   = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaTop     = 0
    MiddleButtonAreaBottom  = 0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made one tweak:

```
$ synclient MaxDoubleTapTime=100
```

It was by default set to **180**.